# Cast a numeric string as float type data

Tags: php, casting, floating-point, type-conversion, decimal

What is the PHP command that does something similar to `intval()`, but for decimals?

Eg. I have string "33.66" and I want to convert it to decimal value before sending it to MSSQL.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about [`floatval()`](http://php.net/floatval)?

```
$f = floatval("33.66");
```

You can shave a few nanoseconds off of type conversions by using casting instead of a function call.  But this is in the realm of micro-optimization, so don't worry about it unless you do millions of these operations per second.

```
$f = (float) "33.66";
```

I also recommend learning how to use [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/sscanf) because sometimes it's the most convenient solution.

```
list($f) = sscanf("33.66", "%f");
```

Comment: Alternative syntax: `sscanf("33.66", "%f", $f);`  <-- this creates a reference variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a float:

```
$var = floatval("33.66")
```

Or

```
$var = (float)"33.66";
```

If you need the exact precision of a decimal, there is no such type in PHP. There is the [Arbitrary Precision Mathematics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension, but it will return strings, so it's only usefull for you when performing calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`floatval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php), but floats are potentially lossy.

You could try running the number through [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to get it to a more correct format.  The format string `%.2f` would produce a floating-point-formatted number with two decimal places.  Excess places get rounded.

I'm not sure if sprintf will convert the value to a float internally for formatting, so the lossy problem might still exist.  That being said, if you're only worrying about two decimal places, you *shouldn't* need to worry about precision loss.

Answer (score -1):

php is a loosely typed language. It doesn't matter if you have

$x = 33.66;

or

$x = "33.66";

sending it to mssql will be the same regardless.

Are you just wanting to make sure it is formatted properly, or is an actual float?

Comment: Well, it turned out that I had single quotations before closing the double quotation brackets. That was the reason why MSSQL was refusing it xD Thanks for the note.

Comment: And MySQL will do string <-> number conversions, too. This is not always a good idea.