# Change a string into an int

Tags: php, string, int

In my store i am trying to change a String into an integer the code which I am using is:

```
<?php echo $_excl; ?>

<?php $int_excl = intval($_excl);?>

<?php var_dump ($int_excl);?>
```

When i `var_dump $int_excl` is says the value is 0 when it should be 4.99 .

What am I doing wrong?

`var_dump ($_excl)` returns `string(33) "£4.99"`

Comment: Try to cast it: like: `echo $int_excl = (int) $_excl;` Also what does this `}` do at the end of the echo statement?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_excl)` say?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($_excl);`?

Comment: Maybe it is floatval() you are looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339628/php-intval-for-decimals

Comment: if typeof($_excl) is really string the (int) $_excl should work.

Comment: How on Earth you expect _intval_ to give you 4.99 (which is a float)? You'd use `floatval` at least.

Comment: var_dump ($_excl) returns string(33) "£4.99"

Comment: Remove the leading symbol then.

Comment: Both [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) (you should use as mentioned above) read the provided string until they reach the first non-numeric character. Read the documentation of these functions and also check [how the strings are converted to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `floatval` and `intval` methods start to look for numbers from the beginning of the string (removing the preceding whitespace) - and stop looking at the first symbol that cannot be a part of the number. In your case, it's the very first one - `£`. That's why `intval` just returns 0 (as `floatval` does).

One way to resolve this is to remove all the non-digit symbols at the beginning of your string with `preg_replace`:

```
$excl = '£4.99';
$value = preg_replace('/^\D+/u', '', $excl);
var_dump(intval($value));   // int(4)
var_dump(floatval($value)); // float(4.99)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/234766). This approach is change-resistant - it works (without any modifications) if `£` is replaced with `$` or any other currency symbol, or dropped altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing float values, and therefore need `floatval()` [PHP Float Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

If `intval()` returns 0, it means that the conversion failed. Source: [PHP Intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php))

In your case, the conversion fails because the string **doesn't start with a number, but with a currency symbol**.

This should solve your problem:

```
<?php 
    echo $_excl;
    $int_excl = floatval(ltrim($_excl, '£'));
    var_dump ($int_excl);
?>
```

(`ltrim` removes the first character if it is `£`)

Comment: He should still get 4 for 4.99!

Comment: True. I guess that the string contains an illegal character at the beginning, which would return 0.

Comment: I get  float(0) when i use floatval

Comment: @AdamAllen The problem is the first character in the string. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$_excl = '4.99' ;//assuming
echo $_excl; 
$int_excl = floatval($_excl);
var_dump ($int_excl);
?>
```

Use above code, since $_excl = 4.99 which is a float value, intval() would return 4.

Comment: This is what i get returned from the var_dump  float(0)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(You have to remove the character `£` from the string)

```
<?php

    $_excl = "£4.99";
    $_excl = str_replace("£", "", $_excl);
    $int_excl = floatval($_excl);
    var_dump ($int_excl);

?>
```

Output:

```
float(4.99)
```